# How to improve reading and transform 300 xml files with python

Tags: python, pandas

I have 300 xml files on my folder.

Each one gives me ~ 1.657 rows when I transform to a dataframe.

The code bellow is taking too much time.

Using R I did in ~200seconds.

The function:  `function_from_xml_pddataframe(xmlfile)`generates the `df_xml_ dataframe`

What am I doing wrong?

How can I improve this process?

```
   import os
    all_dfs = pd.DataFrame()

    
    
    for file in tqdm("/data"):
    
        if file.endswith(".xml"):
          function_from_xml_pddataframe(xmlfile)
          
          df_created = df_xml

          list_of_dataframes.append(df_created)



all_dfs = pd.concat(list_of_dataframes)
```

Answer (score 0):

Without a reproducible example it's hard to be sure. Even replacing your file loop and `function_from_xml_pddataframe` your code won't run as it is:

- `list_of_dataframes` needs to be defined before you can append to it.
- If you meant line 2 to read: `list_of_dataframes = pd.DataFrame()` your code would run slowly and then error at the last line `all_dfs = pd.concat(list_of_dataframes)`.

Assuming you wanted something like this (which is slow, but runs):

```py
import pandas as pd
from scipy.stats import uniform

list_of_dfs = pd.DataFrame()

for i in range(10):
    list_of_dfs.append(pd.DataFrame({'a': uniform.rvs(0, 1, 1000), 'b': uniform.rvs(0, 1, 1000)}))

# this line will cause an error
pd.concat(list_of_dfs)
```

It looks like you're setting up `all_dfs` (or `list_of_dataframes` as it should be) as a pandas dataframe. I think what you're trying to do here is set it up as a list. Try changing line 2 to `list_of_dataframes = []`:

```py
import pandas as pd
from scipy.stats import uniform

list_of_dataframes = []
for i in range(10):
    list_of_dataframes.append(pd.DataFrame({'a': uniform.rvs(0, 1, 1000), 'b': uniform.rvs(0, 1, 1000)}))

pd.concat(list_of_dataframes)
```

The second version is ~10x faster.

**TL;DR**
Make sure you store your separate pandas dataframes in a list - appending to a dataframe is slow.